# Unity3d. Вернуть слово в конце строки

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вопрос такой:
как вернуть слово в конце строки стандартного блока Rect Transform компонента **Text** в Unity?

Например на изображении ниже видим, что в конце строки стоит местоимение "что"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

возможно ли как то в виде строки вернуть последнее слово какой либо строки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копнул глубже, нашел способ словить последнее слово строки Text блока, 
работает как часы:

```
private Text textComp;    //компонент Text
public int lineIndex;     //номер строки

void Start()
{
    //получаем ссылку на компонент Text
    textComp = this.GetComponent<Text>();
}

//сделал в апдейте что бы можно было сразу изменять номер строки в плеймоде (для тестов)
private void Update()
{
    int n = 0;
    //startCharIdx - хранит индекс первого символа строки (вычел 2 что бы сдвинуть индекс с текущего и перепрыгнуть через пробел " ")
    //lineIndex - сделал для смены строки ( в инспекторе тупо что бы менять строку для тестов)
    for (int i = textComp.cachedTextGenerator.lines[lineIndex].startCharIdx - 2; i > 0; i--)
    {
        n++;
        //итеративно добрался до первого пробела " "
        if (textComp.text.Substring(i, 1) == " ")
        {
            //и уже тут получил последнее слово строки (воспользовавшись первой буквой после найденного пробела и инкрементом итераций "n" вовремя перебирания символов)
            string LastLineWord = textComp.text.Substring(i + 1, n);
            Debug.Log("последнее слово строки " + lineIndex + ": " + LastLineWord);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

осталось довести до ума, но это уже другая история :)

Comment: только вряд ли хорошая идея делать это в update. Вынеси в отдельный метод который ты будешь вызывать сразу после изменения текста.

Comment: @Andrew ок, сделал в update для тестов, да вынесу в отдельный метод

Answer (score 1):

Судя по Вашему комментарию к предыдущему ответу, кажется логичным, что Вам будет гораздо проще преобразовать исходную строку, а не работать с ее отображением.

Условно, у Вас есть исходная строка вида `"... 110 км ... 01.01.0001 дата ... 123 какое-то число..."`. Либо распарсьте её на несколько по известным Вам признакам (любым удобным способом), либо модифицируйте её с `Envinronment.NewLine` в опять-таки известных Вам местах.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, думаю да буду копать в эту сторону

Comment: А что конкретно это даст? Он, ведь, все равно не знает какие именно слова окажутся в конце строки для автопереноса без расчетов. А переносить на новую строку каждый кусок который отвечает заданным параметрам - это будет еще более неудовлетворительно выглядеть чем если оставить переносы как есть :)

Comment: @Andrew да.. тут нужно додумать логику переноса слов по заданным параметрам, но благо задачу уже выполнил :) все робит, решение кинул ответом, если кому интересно